# Remote Desktop Connection by making .bat file

Tags: windows, batch-file, remote-desktop

I want to connect my pc to another pc by making .bat file. When i run that file it should connect to the other pc. I wrote "mstsc /v:192.168.15.102" command when i execute this file it  opens remote desktop window and demands username and password. How can i avoid that window and pass the credential  in .bat file.

Answer (score 7):

I found this

```
    cmdkey /generic:TERMSRV/$server /user:$user /pass:$Password
mstsc /v:$Server
```

from [archive](https://web.archive.org/web/20110601004244/http://www.poshpete.com/powershell/passing-username-and-passwords-to-remote-desktop-rdp-automatically) (or [original](http://www.poshpete.com/powershell/passing-username-and-passwords-to-remote-desktop-rdp-automatically))

But I think that's for powershell only and I'm inexperienced with windows.

Along the comments I also saw this one:

For people that were looking for this idea but want to use batch instead I created the following. Save this a mstscup.cmd from notepad (don’t forget to remove the .txt at the end!)
Call it from the command line as follows:
mstscup “servername” “user” “pass”
I didn’t like the idea of leaving the user and pass in the password vault so it clears it after 120 seconds (leaves a command prompt window opened).
Feel free to modify at will!

```
@echo off
setlocal
:: Check if the user passed at least 1 argument
if “%1%” == “” (
echo Remoted Desktop connection with user and password
echo.
echo Missing arguments. Syntax:
echo %~nx0% “servername” “username” “password”
echo.
echo Jean Morin, v0.1, 2013-02-23
pause
goto :eof
)
:: Next line removes surrounding quotes from server name
set sServer=%~1%
:: Keep the quotes for the username and password (in case spaces exists)
set sUser=%2%
set sPass=%3%
:: Seconds to wait before clearing the newly added password from the vault (see control panel, manage your credentials)
:: You may want to modify this if the server takes longer to connect (WAN). You could add this as a fourth argument.
set sSeconds=120
:: Add a new connection definition method to the vault
cmdkey /generic:TERMSRV/%sServer% /user:%sUser% /pass:%sPass%
:: Connect to the server as a new task
start mstsc /v:%sServer%
:: ping ourselves for x seconds (acts like a pause) then removes the newly added password from the vault
ping -n %sSeconds% 127.0.0.1 >nul:
cmdkey /delete:TERMSRV/%sServer%
```

Answer (score 3):

Best solution I could find was saving an rdp config.
Relatively much simpler than these options.
So open Remote Desktop Connection through start menu or `win+r` `mstsc.exe`.
Then select advanced options, change everything you want, and Save As.
This will create an .rdp file that can be clicked to run or run in command prompt.
:)

Answer (score 1):

**Remote Login using java and batch file by double click**

1. Create batch file Remote.bat and write the following code,

   ```
   @echo off
   java Remote DEV
   ```
2. Create a java file Remote.java and write following code,
   also change the IP address of your remote computer in code.

   ```
   import java.awt.MouseInfo;
   import java.awt.Robot;
   import java.awt.event.InputEvent;
   import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
   import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit; 

   public class Remote
   {
       public static void main(String args[])
       {
           try 
           {
               //showPosition();

               System.out.println("Remote Desktop for-->"+args[0]);
               String IP = "";

               if("DEV".equalsIgnoreCase(args[0]))
               {
                   IP = "mstsc /v:10.0.41.101";
               }
               else if("UAT".equalsIgnoreCase(args[0]))
               {
                   IP = "mstsc /v:10.0.45.43";
               }
               else if("PRE-PROD".equalsIgnoreCase(args[0]))
               {
                   IP = "mstsc /v:10.0.45.209";
               }

               Process p = Runtime. getRuntime(). exec(IP);
               Robot bot = new Robot();
               long mask = InputEvent.MOUSE_EVENT_MASK;

               TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep((long) 2.5);

               bot.mouseMove(607, 290);           
               bot.mousePress((int) mask);     
               bot.mouseRelease((int) mask);

               bot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT);
               bot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_Y);
               bot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT);
               bot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_E);
               bot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_S);
               bot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_B);
               bot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_A);
               bot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_N);
               bot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_K);
               bot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_1);

               bot.mouseMove(765, 508);           
               bot.mousePress((int) mask);     
               bot.mouseRelease((int) mask);

           } 
           catch (Exception e) 
           {
               System.out.println("Exception send--->"+e.getMessage());
               e.printStackTrace();
           } 
       }

       public static void showPosition() throws InterruptedException
       {
           try
           {
               while(true == true)
               {
                   TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(1/2);
                   double mouseX = MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation().getX();
                   double mouseY = MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation().getY();
                   System.out.println("X:" + mouseX);
                   System.out.println("Y:" + mouseY);
                   //make sure to import 
               }
           }
           catch(Exception e)
           {
               System.out.println("Excpetion inside showPosition-->"+e.getMessage());
           }
       }


   }
   ```

Now save the code and double click on Remote.bat. 
it will automatically open your remote computer.
Enjoyyyyyyy